# Swift: Alternatives to super class methods to generate objects

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following Objective-C code I'm trying to convert to swift:

```
-(id)initWithBook:(NSString*)bookTitle author:(NSString*)author description:(NSString*)description{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.bookTitle = [bookTitle copy];
        self.author = [author copy];
        self.description = [uri description];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSArray*)listOfBooks:(NSArray*)jsonWithBooks{

    NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *dictElment in jsonRespnse){
        Books *booksData = [[Books alloc] initWithBook:[dictElment objectForKey:@"bookTitle"]
                                                    title:[dictElment objectForKey:@"author"]
                                                      description:[dictElment objectForKey:@"description"]];
        [elements addObject:booksData];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:elements];
}
```

In my Objective-C code I'm calling super class "+(NSArray*)listOfBooks:(NSArray*)jsonWithBooks" to generate NSArray of objects. But I haven't found an equivalente on Swift. Any of you knows what would be the best alternative to do something like this?

I'm trying to use @Alexander example but my project crash in the following line:

```
let inventoryBooks = Book.books(fromDictArray: json .object(forKey: "books") as! [[String : String]] )
```

I check the type for this:

```
json .object(forKey: "books")
```

As follow:

```
let arrayOfBooks = json .object(forKey: "books")
    if arrayOfBooks is NSArray {
        print("nsarray")
    }

    if arrayOfBooks is [[String:String]] {
        print("string:string")
    }
    if arrayOfBooks is NSDictionary {
        print("NSDic")
    }
```

And is printing nsarray

My question. What I'm doing wrong or do I need to change the signature on this function:

```
 static func books(fromDictArray array: [[String: String]]) -> [Book?] {
        return array.map(Book.init)
    }
```

This sample of the json response:

```
{
    books =     (
                {
            caption = "";
            "display_sizes" =(
                                {
                    name = thumb;
                    uri = "https://someUrl.com/img.jpg";
                }
            );
            id = 123;
            "max_dimensions" =             {
                height = 4912;
                width = 7360;
            };
            title = "Learning Swift";
            author = "Some guy"
        }
        {
            caption = "";
            "display_sizes" =(
                                {
                    name = thumb;
                    uri = "https://someUrl.com/img.jpg";
                }
            );
            id = 123;
            "max_dimensions" =             {
                height = 4912;
                width = 7360;
            };
            title = "Swift";
            author = "me meme"
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: That's called a class method, the swift equivalent would be a type method.

Comment: @dan, can you post an example of the type method to see the equivalent of what is on Objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would write this code in idiomatic Swift:

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let description: String

    /* an implicit member wise initializer is generated,
    which would otherwise look something like this:
    init(title: String, author: String, description: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.description = description  
    } */
}

// Initialization from Dictionaries
extension Book {
    init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let title = dict["bookTitle"] as? String,
            let author = dict["author"] as? String,
            let description = dict["description"] as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.init(
            title: title,
            author: author,
            description: description
        )
    }

    static func books(fromDictArray array: [[String: Any]]) -> [Book?] {
        return array.map(Book.init)
    }
}
```

Here are some notable points:

1. `Book` is a struct. Such a broad description of a book doesn't need to support the notion of identity. I.e., your book named "Harry Potter", by "J.K. Rowling" with the description "Some description" can be considered to be the same as my book with the same values. There's no apparent need (yet) to distinguish the identity of your book vs the identity of mine.
2. `Book` has an implicit memberwise initializer `init(title:author:description:)` which simply initializes its fields to the given parameters.
3. An extension is made which compartmentalizes all dictionary related tasks into a single unit.
4. A failable initializer, `init?(fromDictArray:)` is made, which returns a new book based off the given dict (presumably created from your JSON). This initializer is fault tolerant. If the dict provided is invalid, then the initializer will simply return `nil`, without crashing your program.
5. A `static` method is made on the `Book` struct, `books(fromDictArray:)`, which will create an array of optional books (`[Book?]`, a.k.a `Array<Optional<Book>>` out of the given dict. It is then the job of the consumer of this method to deal with the `nil` values, those resulting from invalid dicts, as they please.

   - They could ignore the `nil` books:

     ```
     let books = Book.books(fromDictArray: myDictArray).flatMap{$0}
     ```
   - They could crash if a `nil` book is found:

     ```
     let books = Book.books(fromDictArray: myDictArray) as! [Book]
     ```
   - Or they can handle the nil cases in some unique way:

     ```
     let books = Book.books(fromDictArray: myDictArray).map{ book in
         if book == nil {
             print("A nil book was found")
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: Great solution!
Just 2 minor things I would change. **1)** I would return `[Book]?` instead of `[Book?]` from the static function `books(fromJSONArray:)`. **2)** The body of the func could become `array.flatMap(Book.init)`. But this is just my point of view, this is a really good answer.

Comment: @Alexander, This is great but in your case you don't use class func. Can I ask why?

Comment: @appzYourLife **1)** `[Book]?` would entail you entirely give up just because one book (out of potentially many) gave up. I think it's better to salvage as many as possible, and let the consumer deal with the nil case. **2)** Oh right, I can let the inference engine do the work!

Comment: @user2924482 Class funcs and static funcs are similar in that they're both called on a type. Class functions can be overridden by subclasses, whereas static functions can't. Since structs can't be subclassed, class functions on structs wouldn't be of any use, thus, class functions can only be declared on Classes, whereas static functions are applicable to classes, structs, protocols and even enums.

Comment: On the idiomatic side, why provide a `Book.init` when Swift already provides a nice memberwise initializer for structs?

Comment: @PauloMattos Oh wow, I just learned a really cool thing. Originally, all this code was in the `struct` declaration. In that case, the existence of `init?(fromDict)` would cause the implicit memberwise initializer to not be generated. I eventually split it up into a separate `struct` declaration with a complimentary `extension`. It turns out that `init`s found in extensions won't prevent the formation of the implicit memberwise initializer!

Comment: @Alexander Me too man! I was reading again your code and thinking the *exact* same thing — beautiful hack, haha :-)

Comment: @PauloMattos Discovering little nuggets of knowledge like that are my primary reason for being involved with SO. It's great!

Comment: @Alexander, this is great and I'm trying to use it calling with this code: let inventoryBooks = Book.books(fromDictArray: json .object(forKey: "books") as! [[String : String]] ) but the is crashing because the object is NSArray. How I modify static func books to take NSArray ?

Comment: @user2924482 NSArray probably isnt the issue. I suspect your array's contents aren't strictly NSDictionaries mapping strings to only strings. Can you post what your data structure looks like?

Comment: @Alexander, I have updated my original post. Please let me know if you have any ideas of what is going on

Comment: @user2924482 you havent satisfied my question "Can you post what your data structure look like?". Its an NSArray, okay, what does it contain? Dictionaries? What are the key types of the dictionaries? The values? Give us a real sample to work with

Comment: @Alexander, I post a sample of what the json looks like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142310/discussion-between-alexander-and-user2924482).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioed by *Dan*, the Swift equivalent would be a **`class func`**:

```
class func listOfBooks(jsonWithBooks: [NSDictionary]) -> [Book] {
    var books = [Book]()
    for json in jsonWithBooks {
        let book = Book(
            book: json["bookTitle"]!,        
            author: json["author"]!,        
            description: json["description"]!
        )
        books.append(book) 
    }
    return books
}
```

Comment: It would be better to extract the JSON parsing logic into a bailable initializer, and use `map` instead of `for` and repeated `append` calls. See my answer

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, sure, many ways to factor this! I just provided a straight conversion since the OP is still learning his way around Swift ;-)

Comment: I know many people would disagree, but I'm not fond of this approach. I think it's better to introduce Swift concept right from the start. (otherwise what's the point of using Swift rather Objective C in the first place?) Sure there's more work involved, but writing Objective C style code in Swift is much harder (and sometimes impossible!) than a more idiomatic Swift approach.